# How do I achieve this alternating left-and-right layout in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a webpage containing rows of news tidbits with associated thumbnail images.

```
<div class="news-list">
    <div class="news-item">
        <div class="news-image">
            <img class="news-image" src="penguin.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="news-info">
            <p class="news-info">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit ... sapientem honestatis.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-item">
        <div class="news-image">
            <img class="news-image" src="walrus.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="news-info">
            <p class="news-info">
                Mel et dolores luptatum ... dicta alienum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-item">
    ...
</div>
```

I currently have the page styled with all the images on the left and the descriptions on the right, via the CSS

```
div.news-list { display: table; }
div.news-item { display: table-row; }
div.news-image { display: table-cell; }
div.news-info { display: table-cell; }
```

But I'd like to change this layout to alternate between picture on left and picture on right, as I show in the mockup below:

[image: Mockup of intended CSS layout]

I am having trouble identifying a CSS solution to achieve this layout that doesn't require me to alternate the order of the text tidbits and the images in the actual markup. (I'm happy to put either the images or the text first as necessary, but it ought to be consistent through the whole HTML.)

Any tips?

Comment: As you may have guessed through the tags on your question, use floats. A table-based layout always follows the order of elements in the markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For older-browser support, you could add even and odd classes.

```css
img.news-image {
  background: #dadada;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
p.news-info {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.news-item {
  clear: both;
  border-top: 1px solid #dadada;
}
.odd div.news-info {
  float: right;
}
.odd div.news-image {
  float: left;
}
.even div.news-info {
  float: left;
}
.even div.news-image {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-list">
  <div class="news-item odd">
    <div class="news-image">
      <img class="news-image" src="penguin.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="news-info">
      <p class="news-info">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit ... sapientem honestatis.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="news-item even">
    <div class="news-image">
      <img class="news-image" src="walrus.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="news-info">
      <p class="news-info">
        Mel et dolores luptatum ... dicta alienum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For modern browsers, you could use css pseudo classes.

```css
img.news-image {
  background: #dadada;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
p.news-info {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.news-item {
  clear: both;
  border-top: 1px solid #dadada;
}
.news-item:nth-child(odd) div.news-info {
  float: right;
}
.news-item:nth-child(odd) div.news-image {
  float: left;
}
.news-item:nth-child(even) div.news-info {
  float: left;
}
.news-item:nth-child(even) div.news-image {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-list">
  <div class="news-item">
    <div class="news-image">
      <img class="news-image" src="penguin.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="news-info">
      <p class="news-info">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit ... sapientem honestatis.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="news-item">
    <div class="news-image">
      <img class="news-image" src="walrus.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="news-info">
      <p class="news-info">
        Mel et dolores luptatum ... dicta alienum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I knew floats were going to be involved but my futile attempts at doing it myself didn't have the `clear`s in anywhere close to the right places.

Comment: One question, in the snippets you've included, the top of the `<img class="news-image">` elements and the `<p class="news-info">` elements aren't aligned: the text starts slightly lower than the top of the image. (This was a problem in my css-table layout too.) How can I ensure those elements' tops are aligned?